# DependencyService.Get<T> doesn't return correct instance

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to `Xamarin` and tried some beginner tutorials so far.
Now I wanted to build some custom stuff and need to request the current location.
For this I installed `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location` in order to have access to the `FusedLocationProviderClient` class.

In `MainActivity` I retrieve the `FusedLocationProviderClient`:

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity, ILocationProvider
{
    private FusedLocationProviderClient FusedLocationClient { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // snip

        FusedLocationClient = LocationServices.GetFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }
}
```

The `ILocationProvider` needs the method `TaskCompletionSource<Model.Location> GetPosition()` to be implemented:

```
public TaskCompletionSource<Model.Location> GetPosition()
{
    // snip

    if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission_group.Location) == Permission.Granted)
    {
        FusedLocationClient.LastLocation.AddOnCompleteListener(new OnLocationRequestCompleteListener(this, tcs));
    }

    // snip
}
```

The UI has a button to request the current location.
Whenever the user clicks the button I get the `ILocationProvider` via `DependencyService` and execute the `GetPosition` method:

```
private void GetPositionClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var provider = DependencyService.Get<ILocationProvider>();

    if(provider != null)
    {
        var tcs = provider.GetPosition();

        // snip
    }
}
```

The problem now is that the application crashes as soon as I try to execute the `CheckSelfPermission` method in `GetPosition()`.
I set a breakpoint in `GetPosition()` and noticed that `FusedLocationClient` is `null` although it clearly wasn't `null` after `OnCreate` was called.

I then inspected `this` in `OnCreate` and `GetPosition` and noticed that they weren't the same instances which leads me to the conclusion that something is clearly wrong here.

To solve this for now I did the following:

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity, ILocationProvider
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

    private FusedLocationProviderClient FusedLocationClient { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // snip
        Instance = this
        // snip
    }

    // snip
    public TaskCompletionSource<Model.Location> GetPosition()
    {
        if (this != Instance)
        {
            return Instance.GetPosition();
        }

        // snip
    }
}
```

At least this works for now but I can't imagine that this is the way to go.
What I learned so far is that `DependencyService` seems to not get already created instances but create one instead (at least once).
What would be the correct way to call methods in `MainActivity` from the shared `.NET Standard` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move those methods out of your Activity class into a standalone class (within your Xamarin.Android application (or a Xamarin.Android library project).

#### Assuming an interface like:

```
public  interface ILocationProvider
{
    Task<Tuple<double, double>> GetPosition();
}
```

#### Android Implementation:

```
public class Location_Android: Java.Lang.Object, ILocationProvider
{
    private FusedLocationProviderClient FusedLocationClient { get; set; }

    public Location_Android()
    {
        FusedLocationClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(Application.Context);
    }

    public async Task<Tuple<double, double>> GetPosition()
    {
        var loc =  await FusedLocationClient?.GetLastLocationAsync();
        return new Tuple<double, double>(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Read your comment and created a similar solution like this. I was a bit confused by the Context stuff so I thought it had to be in an Activity. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: @TorbenJ NP... Has to be an Context, Activity or Application... Also you can make this class static and attach an instance of it as a singleton to an Android Application if you need.